# Two different Gateways in one subnet, Client only has a standard gateway

Tags: networking, routing, subnet, gateway

following situation:

- Subnet A: 192.168.0.0/24
- Subnet B: 10.1.1.0/24
- Standard GW  (Router) in Subnet A: 192.168.0.254
- GW leading to subnet 10.1.1.0/24: 192.168.0.100

I want to send traffic from a device in subnet A to a device in subnet B. But the router which is forwarding traffic to subnet B is not my default gw. My actual default GW has a static route to subnet B with gw 192.168.0.100 configured. So I have two gateways in one subnet.

What is best practice for this situation?

1. Do I send traffic to my default gw, which sends the traffic back out the port where the traffic was received, to forward data to my other router? Are the any potential security features on routers which prevent this from happening?
2. Do I have to add a static route to all my hosts in subnet A to lead traffic to subnet B via my secondary router directly - so without contacting my default gw first?

I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance. [My Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IebXy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Although a router is technically a gateway, the clients only have one **Default Gateway**.

You have one router that is connected to the 192.168.0.0/24 network and to your ISP. This router is the default gateway for the 192.168.0.0/24 network.

You have another router which is connected to the 192.168.0.0/24 network that is also connected to the 10.1.1.0/24 network. This router is the router/gateway from the 192.168.0.0/24 network to the 10.1.1.0/24 network, but it is not the default gateway for the 192.168.0.0/24 network.

The clients on 192.168.0.0/24 network don't need to explicitly know about the 10.1.1.0/24 network and they don't need an explicit route to the 10.1.1.0/24 network. Your clients will all use the default gateway on the 192.168.0.0/24 network to reach the 10.1.1.0/24 network.

The default gateway on the 192.168.0.0/24 network has a route to the 10.1.1.0/24 network via the other router on the 192.168.0.0/24 network. The default gateway router on the 192.168.0.0/24 network will happily send an ICMP redirect to clients trying to reach the 10.1.1.0/24 network and instruct them to use the other router on the 192.168.0.0/24 network to reach it.

Answer (score -1):

There's no 100% right way in this case.

On one hand you might want to avoid the extra burden of adding static routes to each host in the network by adding the route on your default gateway. Traffic will be asymmetric as the return path will go directly from 192.168.0.100 to your hosts, but I don't think it's a problem here.

On the other hand if traffic between 192.168.0.0/24 and 10.1.1.0/24 is heavy (specially in the direction from 192. to 10.) you might want to avoid hairpinning that traffic on a single port in 192.168.0.254 as that'll exhaust your bandwidth twice as fast; but in that case you'll have to manually configure the routes on each host in 192.168.0.0/24

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are talking about very little traffic. My main concern is that a router might be "sceptical" to route traffic back out the port where it was received and drops it instead.

Comment: I would check on the router itself and with the vendor. Most would be fine with it, but some vendor might decide they don't like that (there's no big reason to be against that though). Maybe if you mention vendor/model someone can share their experience with it.

Comment: Asymmetric routing is common so the routers won't be "skeptical" but complications are introduced: devices that rely on seeing both directions of a flow (NAT devices or firewalls) may need extra consideration and you may want to disable ICMP redirects on 192.168.0.254 (whether or not they will be generated in this setup is a router-specific question).